# Setup MongoDB to be reachable from remote application

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ubuntu, mongoose

I have a web server that runs MongoDB. It will save some data that I need a second application installed in a different computer to be able to query on. The server with MongoDB is an Ubuntu, it will use Meteor (currently I'm just doing some tests, so I only have the MongoDB installed) and the other application is a NodeJS script with MongooseJS.

What should I do to setup that instance of MongoDB to be reachable from remote applications?

I'm actually finding it quite hard to understand and find information on the web. I tried

```
var connection = GLOBAL.database.host;
mongodb.connect('mongodb://'+GLOBAL.database.host);
```

But it's throwing an error `Failed to connect to.... :27017`

The host is a virtual machine on Koding that I set up to run these tests. How can I make sure Mongo is accessible and how can I ping it to see if the mongo is responding my requests?

Answer (score 3):

By default MongoDB is restricted to allow connections only from `127.0.0.1` .

The configuration file of mongo is placed in /etc/mongod.conf. In that file you can find the following two lines:

```
# Listen to local interface only. Comment out to listen on all interfaces.
bind_ip = 127.0.0.1
```

Follow the instructions and go on commenting the `bind_ip` line (use the # symbol). Restart MongoDB and try again.

Make sure that you can reach your server to port `27017` (is the port that MongoDB uses). You'll have to allow it in your server if you have something like iptables or allow it in any firewall you may have.

Comment: You should ask another question regarding mongodb and windows. You asked for mongodb in an Ubuntu. Did the answer work for you?

Comment: you're right, javier. it's because I uninstalled the mongodb from my ubuntu while I didn't have an answer. but I had it installed on a windows pc, and didnt find the file in the installation folder. then I read the documentation and it seems to be different

Comment: Don't know how it's managed in windows, may be with the process manager. Why don't you reinstall in ubuntu?